# Reshaping database using reshape package

Tags: r, database, reshape

I would like to reshaping some rows of my database. In particular I have some row that it replicate for the Id column. I would like to convert this row in column. I provide a code that it represent a example of my database. 
I'm trying with t() and reshape but it doesn't do that I would. Can anyone give me any suggestions?

```
test<-data.frame(Id=c(1,1,2,3),
    St=c(20,80,80,20),
    gap=seq(0.02,0.08,by=0.02),
    gip=c(0.23,0.60,0.86,2.09),
    gat=c(0.0107,0.989,0.337,0.663))
```

Comment: Can you show us what you expect the output to look like?

Comment: Yes! I expect a final database with one Id for each rows. A final dataframe with 9 different column, something like: Id, St,gap,gip,gat,St2 gap2,gip2,gat2. The values with 2 is referee to a second row of principal database.

Comment: @matte85 You should edit your question and add the expected output in it, it'll be easier for people to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setNames(data.frame(t(test))[2:nrow(data.frame(t(test))),], test$Id)

          1      1      2      3
St  20.0000 80.000 80.000 20.000
gap  0.0200  0.040  0.060  0.080
gip  0.2300  0.600  0.860  2.090
gat  0.0107  0.989  0.337  0.663
```

It helps to provide an expected output. It this what you expected?

Comment: Sure! I would like to ask other question. If I would like to maintain the Id ad row and so transponse the other variable? how can modify the code? Is there a possibility to have integer number for column st?

Comment: To do this you should reordner the columns. There are multiple ways to do this: `test <- test %>% dplyr::select(St, Id, gap, gip, gat)`. You can not have integer numbers here: The reason is because variable types refer ALWAYS to the column. A column can only be a integer, numeric or string, but never a mix. Values get always coerced otherwise. If one value is a string, the whole column will be a string and so on.

Comment: thanks for the availability. One last question (seriously) that came to mind now looking at the result of the operation. If I wanted to just transpose the line with the double id and bring it to the column,the other columns remain as they are how should I do it?

Comment: Open a new question for this topic please. We are happy to help, but one post should not include multiple questions and answers :)